# How to get value from Multi CheckBox with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a multi checkbox with the same attr `name` like `"Check"` but every checkbox has different value

So I have to create a jQuery code that if I press on the checkbox will do some thing in php like this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var NewsPaperId;
   var UserId;
    var CategoryId;
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            NewsPaperId= $('input[name="Check"]:checked').val();
            UserId= $(".userId").val();
            CategoryId= $(".CategoryId").val();
            alert(NewsPaperId);
            $.post("AddAndDelete.php",
                {
                    Add:1,
                    UserId: UserId,
                    NewsPaperId: NewsPaperId,
                    CategoryId:CategoryId
                },
                function(data, status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                 });
         } else {
            NewsPaperId= $('input[name="Check"]:checked').val();
            UserId= $(".userId").val();
            CategoryId= $(".CategoryId").val();

            alert(NewsPaperId);

            $.post("AddAndDelete.php",
                {
                    Delete:1,
                    UserId: UserId,
                    NewsPaperId: NewsPaperId,
                    CategoryId:CategoryId
                },
                function(data, status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the checkbox code created by php

```
<?php

    $i=1;
    $sql = "SELECT NewsPaperStatus.*,UserChoises.*"
         . " FROM NewsPaperStatus"
         . " LEFT JOIN UserChoises"
         . " ON NewsPaperStatus.Id=UserChoises.NewsPaperId"
         . " WHERE NewsPaperStatus.CategoryId=$Categoryid";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      if($i==1){

          if($row['Id']==$row['NewsPaperId']){
             echo '<tr><th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th>';
           }else{
               echo '<tr><th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th>';
             }
         }
         else if($i==2){
             if($row['NewsPaperId']==$row['Id']){
                 echo '<th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th>';
             }else{
                echo '<th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th>';
              }
           }
           else if($i==3){
             if($row['NewsPaperId']==$row['Id']){
                echo '<th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th></tr>';
             }else{
               echo '<th><img src="../images/NewsPaper/'.$row['Logo'].'"/></th><th><a href="">'.$row['Name'].'</a></th><th><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="Check" value="'.$row['Id'].'"/></th></tr>';
            }

       $i=0;
       }
     $i++;
    }
  ?>
```

so the problem is when I press on any check box its work good but when I unchecked another on it take the last vale of check box  (( if I press on checkbox value 16 and press on checkbox value 17 so its work good but when I want to uncheck checkbox of value 16 the value it be 17 its take the last value of checkbox I was checked.

Comment: Not so clear on what you want to get and where are you having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below line:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   NewsPaperId= $('input[name="Check"]:checked').val();
```

You are taking the value of checked checkbox and you have already put the condition of checked in if condition. so my suggestion is to replace the

```
NewsPaperId= $('input[name="Check"]:checked').val();
```

above line with following line:

```
NewsPaperId= $(this).val();
```

And in the else part you need to check if there is any checked checkbox or not. here is code for it:

```
else {
    $('input[name="Check"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
           NewsPaperId= $(this).val();
        }
    });
    if(NewsPaperId != ''){ //do your stuff}
```

Here is the reason to make the if condition. The reason is if user click on checked checkbox and other checkbox is not checked then the value of `NewsPaperId` will be blank else if will take the value of other checkbox which will be checked.

Comment: Thanx, i will do the change and give you the feed back.

Comment: the first part its work fine but the else part return 'undefined' value

Comment: oooohhhh my god its work like a magic ,,,, thanx alot brother ,, i dont know how to thank you ,, thank you sooooooo much you save my life :)

Comment: @kritikaTalwar happy to help you :)